# React Transition Group not working with CSS Transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-transition-group

I have a component where i use React Transition Group. where i am trying to animate one by one each of row's items

```
const SumRow = (props) => {
    const numbers = props.row;
    return (
        <TransitionGroup className = "sinsum__row">
            {numbers.map((number,index) =>
                <CSSTransition in={props.on} key={index} classNames="sinsum__item" timeout={500} >
                    <SumRowItem key = {index}>{number}</SumRowItem>
                </CSSTransition>
            )}
        </TransitionGroup>
    );
};
```

i get strucure in DevTools, but when i change props.on to opposite. CSS transition doesn't even apply styles in DOM.
[first case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmKW3.png)

But when i change RTG to simple div, it starts working.

```
const SumRow = (props) => {
    const numbers = props.row;
    return (
        <div className = "sinsum__row">
            {numbers.map((number,index) =>
                <CSSTransition in={props.on} key={index} classNames="sinsum__item" timeout={500} >
                    <SumRowItem key = {index}>{number}</SumRowItem>
                </CSSTransition>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

[second case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE3lD.png)

What am i doing wrong in first case

Answer (score 0):

CSSTransition requires a nodeRef for each element it parses when used with TransitionGroup. this might help.

```
    const SumRow = (props) => {
const numbers = props.row.map((item, index) => {
 return {number: item,  nodeRef: createRef(null)}
})
return (
    <div className = "sinsum__row">
        {numbers.map((item, index) =>
            <CSSTransition in={props.on} key={index} classNames="sinsum__item" timeout={500} >
                <SumRowItem ref={item.nodeRef} key = {index}>{item.number}</SumRowItem>
            </CSSTransition>
        )}
    </div>
);
```

};